# Assembly x86 - Displaying a string doesn't work on first time

Tags: assembly, x86

I built a code in Assembly 8086 that get's a string from the user, and then it prints it out.

That's my code:

```
        call displayNewLine         ;Displays a new line
        mov [byte ptr si + 14], '$' ;Set's the last char in the string to a $
        add si, 2                   ;Prevent from showing the first two chars (When receiving a string)
        mov dx, si                  ;SI contains the offset where the string starts
        mov ah, 09h         
        int 21h
```

When I run it, it just displays few empty spaces (From what it looks like it only prints out the chars that are between the string and the $).

Screenshot:

[image]

But, for some reason when I add another `int 21h`, it works:

```
    call displayNewLine         ;Displays a new line
    mov [byte ptr si + 14], '$' ;Set's the last char in the string to a $
    add si, 2                   ;Prevent from showing the first two chars (When receiving a string)
    mov dx, si                  ;SI contains the offset where the string starts
    mov ah, 09h         
    int 21h
    int 21h
```

For some reason, this code works and on the second `int 21h` it displays the actual text.

Screenshot:

[image]

displayNewLine:

```
proc displayNewLine                             ;A function that displays a new line
    mov dl, 10
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    ret
endp displayNewLine
```

I tried to move the carrige back to the right, but same happened.

**What causes the text to not be displayed on the first time?**

**If you need more details or better explanation please comment!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boils down to the fact that you've hardcoded where you place the `'$'`.

It gets easier to see what's going on if we initialize the buffer with something other than spaces or NUL-bytes, e.g.:

```
buf: db 10,0,'0123456789ABCDEF'
```

Now, the description of `int 21h / ah=0ah` states that at `buf+2` you'll end up with *"[the] actual characters read, **including the final carriage return**"*.

So if you input "test", your buffer will look like this afterwards:

```
10,0,'test\r56789ABCDEF'    ; \r == carriage return
```

And then you decide to put a `'$'` terminator at `buf+14`, giving you:

```
10,0,'test\r56789AB$DEF'
```

Now you print starting with `buf+2`, which is the same as if you'd been printing `test\r56789AB','$'`.

"test" *will* be printed, but then the carriage returns results in the cursor moving back to the beginning of the current line, and from there it prints the rest of the characters ("56789AB").

When you execute the interrupt for the second time you already have "56789AB" on the current line, and then "test" is printed resulting in "56789ABtest", the carriage return once again moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line, and the rest of the characters are printed (so "56789AB" will be printed over the "56789AB" that were already there).

If instead of "01234..." you had initialized your buffer with spaces or NUL-bytes it would look as if nothing had been printed when you use a single interrupt, and when you use two interrupts you'd get something like:

```
C:\>program
test
       test
```

---

TL;DR: Your input string will contain a carriage return character, and you should probably place the `'$'` at the location of that carriage return rather than at the hardcoded location `[si+14]`.